# How to execute external batch file in CMAKEList

Tags: cmake

Assumption - I have a Generator.bat file which will generate .cpp / .hpp file

I need to write a CMakeList.txt

1.I have couple of Java file say ( A.java and B.Java)
2. If any of the Java file get change , then we need to execute Generator.bat and regenerate the A.cpp and B.cpp and A.hpp and B.hpp files

3. I need to generate a target DLL , from the generated A.cpp and B.cpp and C.cpp (which is user defined) and D.cpp ( which is user defined)
4. We need to generate target DLL
   A) If any of the user defined .cpp file say D.cpp 
       B) if any of the .java file change . Then execute the step 2 and and regenerate the .DLL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `add_custom_command` to teach CMake how to generate your files:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT A.cpp A.hpp B.cpp B.hpp
                   DEPENDS A.java B.java
                   COMMAND generator.bat)

add_library(target SHARED A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp D.cpp)
```

You could have the library depend on A.hpp and B.hpp as well, but you said `generator.bat` regenerates them anyway, so that should not be needed...

Comment: If the solution worked for you, please mark the question as 'accepted' so others can easily find it too.